# Is there a native way to keep a window always on top in Snow Leopard?

Tags: snow-leopard, window-manager

How can you keep one window always on top? I saw that there are several third party solutions, but is there absolutely no way to do it natively?

Comment: How would you indicate which window is on top? Which third party solutions have you rejected (and perhaps why have they failed you?) Specifics help us know what you have in mind.

Comment: Well, I currently use Afloat, but I was thinking that maybe there is native support for this behavior (like in linux) and I'm missing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "native" way to do this. Your existing solution, Afloat, is the only one I've ever heard of (and works quite well).